# Ubuntu MATE 17.10 locks up after boot with latest kernels

Tags: boot, kernel, ubuntu-mate

I've been using Ubuntu MATE 17.10 on my Acer Aspire ES1-572 Laptop for a while, but with one of the recent kernel upgrades my system locks up one second after boot. Before the lockup I can start typing the password or switch to a TTY, but that won't help. This happens with kernel 4.13.0-37-generic and 4.13.0-38-generic, but but kernel 4.13.0-36-generic works fine. I can't find anything useful in the logs. Latest updates are installed.

Comment: This is probably a bug in some driver and will be specific to some hardware component you have and this kernel rather than to MATE. I suggest you report the bug on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and continue to boot the older working kernel until an update fixes the bug, or perhaps install a later kernel yourself. You should add hardware information to this question (make and model). I just tried booting the -38- kernel myself on Ubuntu MATE 17.10 and it works fine for me (on Asus X205TA).

Comment: Yep, I was planning to do that, just wanted to check first if someone else had the same problem and if there was a workaround that I didn't think of. Thanks